# htaccess Rewrite Rule for php to png stopped working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have created several php files that dynamically build images for user rankings. I included an htaccess file in the image directory to translate the php files into png files so that the phpBB board would allow them to be used as ranks. Up until yesterday everything was working fine. I was using the following code in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^rodeojones.png$ rodeojones.php
RewriteRule ^marine.png$ marine.php
RewriteRule ^treble.png$ treble.php
RewriteRule ^major.png$ major.php
RewriteRule ^hyghway.png$ hyghway.php
RewriteRule ^zypher.png$ zypher.php
```

etc... Now, all of the sudden, it isn't working. I am guessing this isn't the most efficient code and therefore it is no longer working for that reason, but I am not sure. This was my first adventure in php so I am lost as to a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: This isn't a PHP question - its an apache question. Can you turn on rewrite logging and show what's logged when you request one of those funky urls? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: How isn't this working? Are you getting an error? What's the error? Is nothing happening at all? What do you see in the logs?

Comment: I tried to create a log but no go... this is what I used in the htaccess file...    `RewriteEngine On  
RewriteLog “logs/rewrite.log”  
RewriteLogLevel 5`  And now it is mysteriously working again. I cannot explain this.

Comment: And the problem was that the php pages were not rewriting. If I went to them by typing the URL for the php in directly they would show up, but when I tried to type the URL for the png in directly I would get an file not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(script)/([^.]*)\.php$ $1/image.png [L]
```

Hopefully will help you, though needs to find more specific to your scenario !